# Компилирование компонентов для разных версий

Tags: delphi, компиляция

Можно ли как то сделать компиляцию моего компонента для разный версий делфи (хочу распространять только `DCU` файлы). Например для `XE-XE5`. Установка всех этих версий - съест много места на диске, есть ли вариант по-проще? Спасибо.

Comment: > Установка всех этих версий - съест много места на диске

Съест много денег в кармане.

Comment: То есть можно не использовать полностью студию, а можно воспользоваться только компилятором?

Comment: компилятором то можно воспользоваться, но если будете уверены, что у других оно удачно соберется. А для этого нужно иметь IDE, что бы тестировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Директивами компилятора {$IFDEF } {$ELSE} и т.д. писать код под все версии delphi, в одном проекте.
Иметь все компиляторы которые хотите поддерживать, и на каждом собирать и тестировать ваши компоненты и код.

Вынимать DCU от ваших компонент, с каждого компилятора и распространять их.

Answer (score 1):

нужно делать dcu для всех версий. Правда вроде была одна пара версий, для которой оно было совместимо.

Лучше распространяйте сорцы.